# Trouble installing Twilio using Pip

Tags: linux, python-2.7, api, pip, twilio

So, I was trying to use the Twilio API and it showed a lot of errors initially. Using the existing aid out there, I could narrow down some errors.

How should I completely install this package? Please let me know if I could share any other information. Thanks.

```
writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
building '_openssl' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:12:24: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <pyconfig.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-
GnLJmL/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --
record /tmp/pip-o1QjZ3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-
build-GnLJmL/cryptography/
```

Edit: A previous version was libpython was required and this isn't really a generic question so I'll close it for now. Thanks Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

Debian, Ubuntu: `sudo apt install libpython2.7-dev`

Fedora, CentOS : # `yum install python-devel` (New Fedora: `dnf install ....` )