# how to add python headers to virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

Working python3.6 on CentOS7.  I create the virtual environment as follows:

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install virtualenv
python3.6 -m virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

in the venv directory, i find my pyvenv.cfg file as expected. the contents are as follows:

```
home = /usr
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.6.8.final.0
virtualenv = 20.14.0
include-system-site-packages = true
base-prefix = /usr
base-exec-prefix = /usr
base-executable = /usr/bin/python3.6
```

The Virtual environment's directory structure looks like this:

```
bin
lib
lib64
```

according [PEP405](https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/), I would expect to see my includes directory (/usr/include/python3.6m/), but it is not there. How can I modify the virtual environment to add this path? I cannot locate any documentation that specifies allowable values for pyvenv.cfg e.g. includes = path-to-headers. I tried post virtual environment creation to make a symlink in the virtual environment directory:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/python3.6m/ include
```

but this doesn't seem to work for my purposes i.e. when trying to compile C++ projects that need the python header files they fail e.g.

```
pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE/EDIT** I just tried creating a virtual environment with venv rather than using virtualenv:

```
python3.6 -m venv new_venv
```

This actually creates the virtual environment directory structure I was mostly expecting:

```
bin
include
lib
lib64->lib
pyvenv.cfg
```

however, the include directory is *empty*, so step forward step backward

Comment: Do you have `python-devel` installed? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43953087/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=centos+pyconfig.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: I do: python3-devel-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64.  I can verify that I can build these C++ modules outside the virtual environment

Comment: my question does seem to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680681/installing-python-dev-in-virtualenv, but not sure i understand the solution explained in the comments: "... once you activate your virtualenv. It changes your PATH variables and so when you do apt-get intsall python3-dev you're installing it into the proper location where the python3 compiler can locate the headers"

Comment: "*…changes your PATH variables and so when you do apt-get intsall python3-dev…*" Don't worry, the comment is completely meaningless. Please take this as a warning ­— StackOverflow is full of bad, incomplete or outright wrong answers and comments written by people who do not understand what they're saying. Never apply any hints from SO (or from the Internet in general) without understanding it.